# guid problem with asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, namespaces, guid

In Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2005 Express Edition, I can't find the type `System.Guid`. Is there problem with my version or do I have another problem? `System.Guid` is not recognized in IntelliSense.

Comment: Does it only not recognize Guid in Intellisense or does it not compile either?

Comment: it doesn't recognize guid in intellisense

Comment: System.Guid is a class, not a namespace.

Comment: System.Guid is a structure - not a class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the proper assemblies, and reference the correct namespaces. Make sure have a reference to `mscorlib.dll` in your project, and that the `System` namespace is imported in the code file (or type `System.Guid` instead of just `Guid`).

To add a reference to a C# project, right click "References", choose "Add reference..." and pick the assembly in the list (or browse, or reference another one of your projects, or whatever you need to do).

In VB.NET, you instead open the project properties (double-click "My Properties") and choose the tab "References" on the left.

Comment: Then, as Chris pointed out, do you have a class named `System` somewhere in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a issue like this before. Have you defined a class called `System`?

Failing that check your references as directed in Tomas's post.